# None is False sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I don't get why None default parameter prints two different things with same syntax.

```
class LoaderForm(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        print("Parent is: " + str(parent))
        self.button_Load.clicked.connect(self.load_project)

    def load_project(self, projectname=None):
        print("pojectname is: " + str(projectname))

>>> Parent is: None
>>> pojectname is: False
```

Why? I double-checked the code several times and I can't find the logic of it. It's worth to mention that I noticed this trying to use a condition for `projectname` inside `load_project` method:

```
        if projectname is None:
            #do something
```

Which of course doesn't works because projectname apparently is False for no reason.

Comment: How do you call `load_project`?

Comment: I also added that bit. I call it just clicking on a pyside2 GUI button. The button connection is made on `__init__`, as you can see in the code above. Later on, I would add another call for it from another method as `self.load_project("whatever")`, which is why I needed a None default parameter (for the situations where I call it just clicking on a button without providing a name).

Comment: @Saelyth  
This is a typical error since the clicked signal passes a Boolean value that by default is false unless you activate the checkeable property of the QPushButton.

Comment: `None` is merely the *default value* **if no value is passed**. Well… a value *is* being passed, namely `False`.

Comment: @Saelyth http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked

Comment: Yeah, that's it @eyllanesc, somehow I missed that... for 6 months. /Facepalm

Comment: @Saelyth I meet him every so often in the questions :), he is a well-known friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is a first class object in Python. It can be passed to another function, just like any other object. This is exactly what is happening with `self.button_Load.clicked.connect(self.load_project)`.

So you need to look at what `self.button_Load.clicked.connect` is doing with your `self.load_project` method. Here, it is passing the argument `False`, which overrides the default `None`.

Here's a minimal example to reproduce your issue:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.connect(self.foo)

    def connect(self, func):
        func(False)

    def foo(self, var=None):
        print('Var is ' + str(var))

A = MyClass()

# Var is False
```

Comment: This helps me to understand it. I will have to play with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think `clicked` has a parameter with a default, like `clicked=false` which is forwarded to `load_project` and overrides `projectname=None`